# Django/python How to get a list of id's from a list of Objects

Tags: django, django-models

If I have a list of objects acquired by some query (in this case Django models).

```
friends = Friend.objects.friends(user1)
```

How can I get the list of ids, so I can use it to search another model, like this:

```
items = Item.objects.get(pk__in=friends_ids).order_by('date')
```

I'm pretty sure the lambda expressions should be able to do it but I can't figure it out...

Answer (score 36, accepted):

If the return value of the `friends` method is a [`QuerySet`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) object, you can use [`QuerySet.values_list`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.1/ref/models/querysets/#values-list) method:

```
friends_ids = friends.values_list('id', flat=True)
```

If it's not a `QuerySet` object, you can use [list comprehension](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#list-comprehensions) (This one can be used for both `QuerySet` and non-QuerySet one):

```
friends_ids = [friend.id for friend in friends]
```

Comment: It returns a list, no queryset. Good point in using the list comprehension... I was thinking way to complex and completely forgot about such an easy solution :).