# return list of ids in a Get. Django Rest Framework

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a model called "document-detail-sample" and when you call it with a GET, something like this, **GET** `https://url/document-detail-sample/` then you get every "document-detail-sample".

Inside the model is the id. So, if you want every Id, you could just "iterate" on the list and ask for the id. Easy.

But... the front-end Developers don't want to do it :D they say it's too much work...

So, I gotta return the id list. :D

I was thinking something like **GET** `https://url/document-detail-sample/id-list`

But I don't know how to return just a list. I read [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27647871/django-python-how-to-get-a-list-of-ids-from-a-list-of-objects) and I know how to get the id_list in the backend. But I don't know what should I implement to just return a list in that url...

the view that I have it's pretty easy:

```
class DocumentDetailSampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DocumentDetailSample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentDetailSampleSerializer
```

and the url is so:

```
router.register(r'document-detail-sample', DocumentDetailSampleViewSet)
```

so:

**1**- is a good Idea do it with an url like `.../document-detail-sample/id-list"` ?

**2**- if yes, how can I do it?

**3**- if not, what should I do then?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `@list_route` decorator

```
from rest_framework.decorators import detail_route, list_route
from rest_framework.response import Response

class DocumentDetailSampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DocumentDetailSample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentDetailSampleSerializer

    @list_route()
    def id_list(self, request):
        q = self.get_queryset().values('id')
        return Response(list(q))
```

This decorator allows you provide additional endpoint with the same name as a method.  `/document-detail-sample/id_list/`
[reference to docs about extra actions in a viewset](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/viewsets/#marking-extra-actions-for-routing)

Comment: nice, and how does it work? I mean, what should the front-end-developer do to take it?

Comment: @ChuckAguilar you're welcome. better thank me with thumbs up or submit an answer :)

Comment: I'm waiting the 3 minutes :P

Comment: Answer should be updated. @list_route() is deprecated: https://www.django-rest-framework.org/community/3.8-announcement/#deprecations https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31490341/

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you don't need pagination, just override the `list` method like so

```
class DocumentDetailSampleViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = DocumentDetailSample.objects.all()
    serializer_class = DocumentDetailSampleSerializer


    def list(self, request):
        return Response(self.get_queryset().values_list("id", flat=True))
```

Comment: thanks for your answer :) But I prefer the solution of Ivan, because it's how I thought it. :) But many thanks!